# List directories in amazon S3 with AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to list folders in S3:

```
string delimiter = "/";
folder = "a/";
ListObjectsResponse r = s3Client.ListObjects(new Amazon.S3.Model.ListObjectsRequest()
{
  BucketName = BucketName,
  Prefix = folder, 
  MaxKeys = 1000,
  Delimiter = delimiter
});
```

and i expect list of directories such as:

```
a/Folder1
a/Folder2
....
a/FolderN
```

but my actual result is only 1 object:
**'a1'**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Folders are not treated as objects in S3.

Instead, I need to read **string[] CommonPrefixes** property, which has my subfolders